# Can we use yx5300 to play audio from a file in Arduino?

Tags: sound

I want to play a file that I have in my USB device through a yx5300 mp3 module.

I have a file in my USB device at path `Music/hello.mp3`. I want to play this file using the yx5300 module or some other module, if available.

I have already read this file using a shield. I want to pass the data to the yx5300.

Answer (score 2):

No. That chip can only play files on an SD card that is directly attached to it.

Comment: So what else can I use..??

Comment: The Itead music player shield (https://www.itead.cc/wiki/ITEAD_Music_Player_Shield) may be of use. It can play direct from a USB memory stick.

Comment: This shield is unavailable ...Can you tell any other or where to buy....

Comment: No better than Google can.

Comment: https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Music_Shield?files=1.  Can this library for music shield provided by seed used with any other music shield